# Is it possible to populate my wordpress site with many random posts for testing purposes?

Tags: automation, testing

I have just deployed the Wordpress application on my Kubernetes cluster following the instructions from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

Now I would like to populate the Wordpress database with a lot of posts for testing purposes. I do not really care about the content of these posts. As far as I am concerned they can be completely random. All I care that there are a lot of them.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can use [WP REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) to send POST request to create posts. Or probably just import a database dump.

Comment: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/search/dummy/

Comment: @Sisir - POST requests does not solve my problem, because I still need to generate somehow the content for these requests. As for the database dump - gladly. Where can I get such a dump?

Comment: @vancoder - could you elaborate?

Comment: You can send lorem ipsum text as contents, titles etc. Also checkout this plugin see if this helps https://wordpress.org/plugins/fakerpress/

Comment: There is official test data for testing themes available here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test

Comment: @JacobPeattie - this is much better. It brings 49 posts. Not much, but it is a start. Could you arrange your comment as an answer so that I could credit you? Maybe you know an even larger set of dummy data, like a mysql dump maybe?

Comment: @Sisir - I will try your suggestion of installing fakerpress.

Comment: @Sisir - fakerpress looks so far very promising. Can you promote your comment to an answer so that I could credit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are using Kubernetes. There are few routes you could go.

1. **REST API:** Write a light script (nodejs or php) that creates fake data and sends to rest route to create posts. You can then use cron hit rest route for creating posts.
2. **Plugin:** Check [Fakerpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fakerpress/) plugin, I haven't used it but it looks like something you can use.

Answer (score 1):

There is official test data available here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test

It's an XML file that you can import from *Tools > Import* and imports a variety of posts, pages, and menus for the purpose of testing themes.